# Riemann form for product of elliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a simple description of the Riemann form on $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$ of the Abelian variety which is the product $E_1\times E_2$ of two elliptic curves?

Comment: Do you mean for the product polarization? Then it is $H_1\oplus H_2$ where $H_i$ is the Riemann form of $E_i$. For this type of basic questions, please use [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com).